# How to capture a change in an element of an array in TLA+

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, tla+

I am specifying a system whose state consists of a sequence:

```
VARIABLE Seq
```

The sequence is constrained to be of a certain type:

```
TypeInvariant == Seq \in [Nat -> [v1: {0,1}, v2: {0,1}]]
```

I want to allow, in the state machine, a transition of this type:

> The system can move from a certain state to another where any of its elements gets its named property `v2` changed from `0` to `1`.

So, basically, in the sequence `Seq`, any element is allowed to cause a transition where the new sequence `Seq'` remains "the same" (same number of elements), but one element only changes:

```
[v1 |-> 0, v2 |-> 0]   ====>   [v1 |-> 0, v2 |-> 1]
```

#### How to write it in TLA+?

How do you specify such an action in TLA+? I have tried thinking about something like this:

```
\E s \in Seq : (s' = [s EXCEPT !.v2 = 1] /\ s.v2 = 0)
```

But I am really not sure if this is the way because I am priming something which is not a declared variable. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* prime something that's not a declared variable, as long as A) it's part of a declared variable, and B) the variable was primed in a previous clause. In this case it acts as a constraint (the action won't happen if the clause is false.)

For your case, what you want to do is change the whole sequence at once:

```
\E i \in 1..Len(S):
   /\ S[i].v2 = 0
   /\ S' = [S EXCEPT ![i].v2 = 1]
```

Note that `Len` is from `EXTENDS Sequences`, if you don't want to import that, you can use `DOMAIN S` instead of `1..Len(S)`. `Sequences` also imports the `Seq` operator, which is why I suggest renaming your variable to something else, like S.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I am gonna give this a try and let you know :)

Comment: As I get to try this... a question: is this covered by the book from Lamport or somewhere in some shared doc? I am using Lamport's book as my primary reference and I could not see this covered. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: Yeah it works fine, thanks a lot!